# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'`

Tags: c#, entity-framework, join

I have the following 3 tables structured in the way as shown below. I'm trying to write an entity framework join query among the 3 tables
to retrive `joblink, usersubmitted, runstatus, submitted_time, changelist orderby submitted time`.

I have a holder class to return the output...please note that gerrits is a `List<string>` as its possible to have multiple values for a single run, this is  where I am getting the error..,can anyone provide guidance on how to fix the error or is there a better practice to achieve this?

HOLDER CLASS:-

```
namespace Dashboard.Model.ApiModels
{
    public class LookaheadRunInfo
    {
        public string ECJobLink { get; set; }
        public List<String> changelists { get; set; }
        public string UserSubmitted { get; set; }
        public string SubmittedTime { get; set; }
        public string RunStatus { get; set; }
    }
}
```

API:-

```
    public IEnumerable<LookaheadRunInfo> GetLookaheadRunInfoSearch(LookaheadRunsFilterCriteria filterCriteria)
    {
        List<LookaheadRunInfo> lookaheadRunsInfo = new List<LookaheadRunInfo>();
        var lookaheadRunData = bitDB.lookahead_run.OrderByDescending(x => x.lookahead_run_id).Skip(filterCriteria.PageNumber * filterCriteria.PageSize).Take(filterCriteria.PageSize).ToList();
        foreach (var lookaheadRunRow in lookaheadRunData)
        {
            var lookaheadRunId = lookaheadRunRow.lookahead_run_id;
            var lookaheadRuns = new LookaheadRunInfo();
            lookaheadRuns = (from lrcl in bitDB.lookahead_run_change_list
                                             join cl in bitDB.change_lists on lrcl.change_list_id equals cl.change_list_id
                                             join lr in bitDB.lookahead_run on lrcl.lookahead_run_id equals lr.lookahead_run_id
                                             where lrcl.lookahead_run_id == lookaheadRunId
                                             orderby lr.submission_time
                                             select new LookaheadRunInfo
                                             {
                                                 ECJobLink = lr.ec_job_link,
                                                 //gerrits = cl.change_lists.Select(x => x.change_list.ToString()).ToList(),
                                                 changelists = cl.change_list.ToString(),
                                                 UserSubmitted = lr.submitted_by,
                                                 SubmittedTime =lr.submission_time.ToString(),
                                                 RunStatus = lr.lookahead_run_status,

                                             }).ToList();
            lookaheadRunsInfo.Add(lookaheadRuns);
        }
        return lookaheadRunsInfo;
    }
```

TABLES:-

```
lookahead_run (Table#1) 
+-------------------+--------+----------------+-------------------+----------+
lookahead_run_id(PK)|joblink |  usersubmitted |submitted_time     |runstatus
+-------------------+--------+----------------+-------------------+----------+
15963---------------+link1---+---username1----+2017-03-17 22:28:53--Fail-----

lookahead_run_change_list (Table#2)
+---------------+----------------+-----------------+
changelistid(PK)|lookahead_run_id|change_list_id
+---------------+----------------+-----------------+
38591-----------+15963-----------+34022
38590-----------+15963-----------+34021
38589-----------+15963-----------+34020


change_lists (Table#3)
+-------------+-----------+
change_list_id|changelist
+-------------+-----------+
34022--------  1823900
34021--------  1819483
34020--------  1818572
```

Error:-

`Error  1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'`

Comment: Which line shows that error?

Comment: @unlucky - `changelists = cl.change_list.ToString(),` shows the error

Comment: are you sure it returns you a collection of cl.change_list for each ECJobLink, and not multiple LookaheadRunInfo objects that differ only by cl.change_list value?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into the class definition, `changelists` is defined as a List, now take a look into the query, here you are assigning `cl.change_list.ToString()` to the List Of string. and that's the same error message is saying, You are trying to assign a string value to a List of strings.

**Fix**

If you are sure about the Datatype of the `changelists` is List then remove that `.ToString()` from the query and use `.ToList()` instead. if `changelists` is string means make necessary changes in the property definition.

Comment: changing to `ToList()` gives an error `Error 1 'int' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Could you please explain, What you are trying to do in that place?

Comment: if you see my database table...you will notice that its possible that for a single lookahead run id we can have multiple changelists, am trying to retrieve these `changelist` value from  `change_lists` table into a List<string>